# Nested WebGLRenderTargets in three.js

Tags: javascript, opengl-es, three.js, webgl, render-to-texture

I'm writing an Oculus Rift application using JavaScript / three.js / OculusRiftEffect.js.

For the menu, I need to mask out parts of a 2D ring as transparent. I'm trying to do this by generating a `MeshBasicMaterial.alphaMap` texture on a `WebGLRenderTarget`. The problem is, `OculusRiftEffect.js` also uses a `WebGLRenderTarget`, and they seem to be conflicting. Specifically:

Setting up the objects to render the texture:

```
menuAlphaScene = new THREE.Scene();
menuAlphaCamera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, 1, 0.1, 1000); // probably should use orthographic camera here, but meh effort
menuAlphaCamera.position.z = 1;
menuAlphaRT = new THREE.WebGLRenderTarget(512, 512, { minFilter: THREE.LinearFilter, magFilter: THREE.NearestFilter, format: THREE.RGBFormat });
```

Attaching the texture to the object (I'm aware that I'm using `map` instead of `alphaMap`, this is just to debug the texture contents more easily):

```
menuObject = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.RingGeometry(0.7, 1, 30, 30), new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    side: THREE.DoubleSide,
    map: menuAlphaRT
}));
```

Actually rendering the texture:

```
function regenMenuAlphaTexture(sixth) {
    var rtScene = new THREE.Scene();
    if (sixth >= 0) { // - 1 = none selected
        var angle = 2 * Math.PI / 6 * sixth;
        var obj = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.RingGeometry(0.5, 1, 30, 30, angle, angle + 2 * Math.PI / 6), new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
            color: 0xaaaaaa,
            side: THREE.DoubleSide
        }));
        rtScene.add(obj);
    }
    renderer.setClearColor(0xff0000, 1);
    renderer.render(rtScene, menuAlphaCamera, menuAlphaRT);
}
```

What I'm running inside `requestAnimationFrame`:

```
function render() {
    update();
    renderer.clear();
    regenMenuAlphaTexture(0);
    oculusRiftEffect.render(scene, camera);
    //renderer.render(scene, camera);
    requestAnimationFrame(render);
}
```

When using `oculusRiftEffect`, the texture is black. When using `renderer.render`, the ring correctly renders.

There's no GL errors that I can see (at least not reported in the console by three.js). I'm really not sure what's going wrong here.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `OculusRiftEffect` I would recomend using `VREffect` and `VRContols` and a [Firefox VR build](http://blog.bitops.com/blog/2014/08/20/updated-firefox-vr-builds/) or [Chrome VR build](http://blog.tojicode.com/2014/07/bringing-vr-to-chrome.html).

Comment: I'm pretty excited for those, however my development platform is Linux-based, and currently there are only builds for Windows/OSX. (Also since you made three.js I just want to say it's an awesome library thank you)